# Filter with a field whose name is referenced in another field

Tags: mongodb

We are moving some legacy service running on RethinkDB to MongoDB and I am having troubles with in a situation which is trivial in RethinkDB.

We have a structure

```json
{
    "user_id": <user_id>,
    "state": {
        <user_id>: 1  // 2, 3, etc
    }
}
```

In RethinkDB this is trivial, as I said, something like

```js
r.db('db').table('db').filter(function(item) {
  return item("state")(item("user_id")).default(0).eq(1)
}).limit(5)
```

Is there an easy way in Mongo? Or "$objectToArray" juggling only?

Comment: Have you tried with `$expr` and `$eq`?

Comment: @Joe no, haven't tried it. Thank you for the hint, will check it out.